# mgcv: Fix smoothing parameter in GAMM and validity of model nesting

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I am currently trying to model the interaction between a covariate `x` (Age) and a gender 0-1 variable with `gamm` from the `mgcv` package. After specifying a main model (lets call it `M0`) with a smooth term for each gender, I would like to test the simpler hypothesis that the difference between genders is linear (and not arbitrarily smooth). I have the following two questions:

1. When trying to nest the models properly I would like to get out the smoothing parameter for the 0-gender smooth from `M0`, and use it in the simpler model specification. But I get the following error message:

> Error in gamm.setup(gp, pterms = pTerms, data = mf, knots = knots, parametric.only = FALSE,  :
>
> gamm can not handle linked smoothing parameters (probably from use of `id' or adaptive smooths)

2. Second question is the more stupid one. Are the models even nested when I go from a smooth for each gender to a 0-gender smooth and a linear difference to 1-gender?

Below follows an example. I simulated some random data, so the data does not display the behaviour of my actual data, but the problems remain the same.

```
library(mgcv) 

### Simulate random data
x <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1.5)
y <- rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.025)

id <- sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = T)
id <- as.factor(id)

gender <- sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = T)


### Specify main model, M0
ctrl <- list(niterEM=0,optimMethod="L-BFGS-B", msMaxIter = 100)
M0 <- gamm(y~s(x, by = as.factor(gender)) + gender, 
           random=list(id=~1+x), control=ctrl)

### Specify model with linear difference between gender0 and gender1
M1 <- gamm(y~s(x) + gender:x + gender, 
           random=list(id=~1+x), control=ctrl)

### Testing
anova(M0$lme, M1$lme)

### Problems:
sp0 <- M0$gam$sp[1]
M1 <- gamm(y~s(x, sp = sp0) + gender:x + gender, 
           random=list(id=~1+x), control=ctrl)
```

> Error in gamm.setup(gp, pterms = pTerms, data = mf, knots = knots, parametric.only = FALSE,  :
>
> gamm can not handle linked smoothing parameters (probably from use of `id' or adaptive smooths)

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sp doesn't work in gamm, only in gam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Regarding the `gamm` error

This is a very interesting thing... Well, I should explain the logic first.

In principle **it is illegal to fix a smoothing parameter in `gamm`**, because `gamm` will treat the wiggly components of the smooth as random effects, the variance of which to be estimated by `lme` (as you have Gaussian data). If you try to fix the smoothing parameter, that is essentially saying that you want to fix the variance of the random effect. Well, `lme` does not allow you to do this (and I doubt whether such attempt is legal in mixed modelling, either.)

Therefore `gamm` would disable any possible constraints on smoothing parameters, including:

1. lower bound of smoothing parameter, via `min.sp`;
2. linked smooth sharing the same smoothing parameter, via `id` in `s()`;
3. directly specified smoothing parameter via `sp`, via `s()`.

The first two are perfectly checked. `gamm` has no `min.sp` argument like `gam`; even if you specify it via `...`, there is no chance it would get used (as later it's `NULL` that's passed to `gam.setup` during `gamm.setup`, so your specified `min.sp` is ignored). Specification of `id` will also be detected by the error message you saw, but of course you did not specify `id` so the above error is not reporting the correct issue here, hence a bug.

The third one, actually has not been directly checked via `gamm`. Ideally, as soon as the `gamm` / `gam` formula has been interpreted (by `interpret.gam`), `sp` should be reset to `-1` if it is not readily is, and a warning message about this should be issued. However, this part is missing. Therefore, at the moment the best thing you can do is just not specifying `sp`.

---

## Do you have valid model nesting?

Now let's turn to your concern on nesting. **Nesting is related to basis set up rather than choice of smoothing parameter.** As long as you have the same set of basis (same basis type, same number and / or location of "knots"), the model matrix will be the same. For example, in your model `M0` and `M1`, you have the same configuration of the `s()` with `mgcv` default `bs = 'tp', k = 10`. So the design matrix for `s()` is the same in your two models. The `by = factor(gender)` just replicates this `s()` to all levels of `gender` in your main model `M0`. Perhaps it is not easily seen, but actually your `M1` is nested in `M0`.

Let's consider a small example to verify this. For simplicity, I will not use `s(x)` from `mgcv`, but use `poly(x, degree = 2)` (imagining it is `s(x)`). Let's generate some toy data first:

```
x <- 1:10
f <- gl(2, 5, labels = c("M", "F"))
```

Since `f` is not an ordered factor, `s(x, by = factor(f))` generates design matrix by replicating `s(x)` for all levels of `f`:

```
## original design matrix for `s(x)`
X0 <- poly(x, 2)
## design matrix for `f`, without contrasting
Xf <- model.matrix(~ f + 0)
## design matrix for level `M`
X1 <- X0 * Xf[, 1]
## design matrix for level `F`
X2 <- X0 * Xf[, 2]
## design matrix for `s(x, by = f)` "please, imagine it as `poly`"
X <- cbind(X1, X2)

#                1           2          1           2
# [1,] -0.49543369  0.52223297 0.00000000  0.00000000
# [2,] -0.38533732  0.17407766 0.00000000  0.00000000
# [3,] -0.27524094 -0.08703883 0.00000000  0.00000000
# [4,] -0.16514456 -0.26111648 0.00000000  0.00000000
# [5,] -0.05504819 -0.34815531 0.00000000  0.00000000
# [6,]  0.00000000  0.00000000 0.05504819 -0.34815531
# [7,]  0.00000000  0.00000000 0.16514456 -0.26111648
# [8,]  0.00000000  0.00000000 0.27524094 -0.08703883
# [9,]  0.00000000  0.00000000 0.38533732  0.17407766
#[10,]  0.00000000  0.00000000 0.49543369  0.52223297
```

Your second model `M1`, has only a smooth term `s(x)`, the design matrix of which is `X0`.

Here is how we can see that your `M1` is nested in `M0`:

1. As `X1 + X2 = X0`, design matrix of `s(x)` and `s(x, by = f)` have the same column span, thus `s(x)` is nested in `s(x, by = f)`;
2. since `x` is nested in `s(x)`, `x:f` is nested in `s(x, by = f)`.

---

## What I would do

Although you models are already nicely nested, the main model `M0` does not have a comparable interpretation with your `M1`. Your main model `M0` will end up with an independent smooth for each level, while your `M1` focus on the difference between two groups.

It would be good if we could control `M0` to admit a form of "reference smooth + difference smooth". Then, if the difference smooth turns out a line, without actually fitting `M1` we already know there is no evidence for non-linear difference between groups.

In `mgcv`, difference smooth will be constructed, if your factor is ordered. So I suggest you fit your main model by:

```
gender1 <- ordered(gender)  ## create an ordered factor
s(x) + s(x, by = gender1) + gender
```

If estimation result shows the difference smooth `s(x, by = gender1)` as a line, you know you can instead fit a simpler model

```
s(x) + gender:x + gender
```

even without using `F-test`.

Note, it is very important to have an ordered factor `by` in order to construct "difference" smooth. If you do

```
s(x) + s(x, by = gender) + gender  ## note, it is "gender" in "by"
```

`s(x)` and `s(x, by = gender)` are completely linearly dependent. The resulting model matrix will be **rank-deficient**.

---

## Some follow-up

> I forgot to include in my example that I at first compared the same model parametrized as `s(x, by = as.factor(gender))` and `s(x) + s(x, by = gender)` by AIC (recall `gender` is 0-1 numerical variable). These models are statistically equivalent, but the smoothing parameters are obviously estimated differently in the cases, and the AIC thus differ a bit.

Oh, yes. Your `gender` is binary so a numerical `by` is also a good idea for constructing a difference smooth. But do this with care. Numerical `by` does not yield a centred smooth. Therefore, `s(x) + s(x, by = gender)` will implicitly have an intercept column, confounded with the model intercept. You should go with `s(x) + s(x, by = gender) - 1`.

Comment: Okay - apparently I have missed the fact that it is treated as a random effect. I will keep myself from explicitly specifying it then. Thank you. 
I do not know, if I am supposed to ask this question in a comment, but how would you then assess whether the simple model given in my example describes the data as well as the complex model? Without the models being nested my conclusions from the anova call seems very approximate. Mads

Comment: I forgot to include in my example that I at first compared the same model parametrized as `s(x, by = as.factor(gender))` and `s(x) + s(x, by = gender)` by AIC (recall gender is 0-1 numerical variable). These models are statistically equivalent, but the smoothing parameters are obviously estimated differently in the cases, and the AIC thus differ a bit. With my data at hand that yielded the first case. Hence the reason for having this as the base model.
With my interest being to test if the difference between gender is linear, would you then choose s(x) + s(x, by = gender) as base?

Comment: Thank you for your great response - it makes perfect sense. I will refrain my self from trying to fix the smoothing parameter also. As explained, the reason for me to initially model the data with two seperate smooths was due to a (pretty small) difference in AIC. However I looked at the `gam` objects when parameterized both ways, and in the 'difference smooth' approach the difference did indeed seem linear - hence the reason for my interest in testing.
Have a nice day. Thank you,
Mads

Comment: I do not follow you regarding the "reference" smooth case. To me it is exactly the same to use `s(x) + s(x, by = gender)` and `s(x) + s(x, by = gender1) + gender1` where `gender` is numerical 0-1 and `gender1` is ordered factor. The `df` and `LogLik` are also the same in these cases (`LogLik` only approximately). By writing `s(x) + s(x, by = gender) - 1` as you suggest (if I want numerical `gender`), I decrease the `df` of the `lme` object with one.